# В каком формате хранить большой обьем данных при работе в C#? (1)

Tags: c#, csv

Предыдущий мой вопрос закрыли, после правок не открывают. Создаю новый (в правилах написано что можно)

Ребят! Есть большой массив котировок (ну, до гигабайта), при первом запуске программы - берем его из *.csv файла.

Подскажите - в чем лучше всего хранить информацию (типа дата, int, int, int, int)? Т.к. при каждом запуске программы надо будет опять подгружать его. Ну или оперативно заменить на другой.

А, и в чем лучше всего хранить данные с файла в самом C#? 
Я про конкретный формат: один массив/список или список/массив для каждого значения? А может есть какие более "корректные способы" работать с подобным?
Надо будет постоянно гонять его в циклах.

Буду рад помощи/ссылкам на подсказки как это делать более правильно :)

***---upd. 1---***

**Кто сохраняет ваши котировки?**

Я, экспортирую из торговой платформы МетаТрейдер. В дальнейшем планирую получать от куда нибудь напрямую из интернетов.

**Обязательно ли их сохранять в csv?**

Исторически сложилось - вообще не обязательно. Было бы интересно узнать в чем хранить правильней)

**Нужно ли все эти данные разом выгружать? Надо ли их перезаписывать?**

Желательно. Данные нужны только на чтение. Обновляться они будут другими инструментами.

Работа с файлом выглядит так - нашли нужную дату, на указанное количество дней (в одном дне - 1440 записей) производим различные арифметические/статистические расчеты. Просто пробегаем каждую запись и делаем вид что у нас "реальная" торговля. 
Методы выглядят так - сообщить о количестве записей в массиве, открыть "виртуальную сделку" на указанный день.

Данные выглядят как 5 значений типа int: (Дата,open,high,low,close).

Comment: Чтобы просто пробегать по данным вам подойдет массив.

Comment: формат файла *.массив?

Comment: Формат файла то тут причем? Формат выбирайте любой, который вам удобно читать. Я бы выбрал любой, который удобно читать построчно.

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) по крайней мере для чтения можно использовать. Создаете класс с нужными свойствами, читаете данные в коллекцию таких классов, делаете вычисления, затем пишите в тот же `csv` или `json`, или `xml`, или в БД.

Comment: Ну, получается просто работать с большим csv файлом и подгружать его при каждом запуске это нормально? А данные из него просто сложить в один большой двумерный массив и гонять его в циклах это тоже считается эффективным кодом? Без сарказма, просто пытаюсь понять - норм это вариант или можно что нибудь другое придумать. По этому и спрашиваю у опытных Си-шарперов :)

Comment: Код считается эффективным в конкретных сценариях использования. Вы никаких сценариев не предоставили. Вот будет у вас какой то код, как вы узнаете, что он эффективный? Какие метрики кода вы измерите? Как вы его запустите?

Comment: Обычно, когда перед программистом стоит задача — он пишет изначально код, который хотя бы как то работает. А после этого программист запускает свою программу и, если видит какие то в ней проблемы (например, что то работает неприемлемо медленно), то тогда этот программист находит участок кода, который работает медленно, замеряет скорость работы этого участка, потребляемую память и другие метрики, после чего производит оптимизацию и замеряет метрики снова, чтобы понять,  решена проблема или нет. В вашем вопросе вы зачем то пытаетесь решить проблему, которой у вас еще нет.

Comment: Вы начали с конца, у вас нет ни проблемы, ни метрик. Если вы не знаете вашу проблему и у вас нет никаких метрик, то вы просто теряете время, что бы вам не посоветовали — это будет гадание на кофе. Если у вас проблема с потребляемой памятью - то читайте файл частями. Если у вас проблема с производительностью - читайте файл в память.  Если у вас проблема с алгоритмической сложностью сгруппировать данные - используйте словарь. Если у вас проблема с ооп - читайте про паттерны. Пока что я не вижу у вас четкой проблемы - то есть ваш вопрос попросту ни о чем.

Comment: Можно сказать что проблема в разработке архитектуры?) ну ладно, понял вас. Вопрос можно закрыть, если появятся какие то проблемы со скоростью постоянной подгрузки *.csv преобразование его в массив и последующей работы с ним - отпишусь еще раз. Спасибо всем за отзывы!

Comment: Если Вы к кому то обращаетесь в комментариях - указывайте его ник вот так @Pavel , чтобы он получил уведомление. Мне этого делать не надо, так как вы получите уведомление о любом комментарии под вашим вопросом.

Comment: Ну или используйте БД если это актуально в вашем решении. Посмотрите в сторону использования SQLite (учтите что SQLite не является клиент-серверной архитектурой) если вы хотите именно при каждом запуске подгружать файл снова. Или смотрите в сторону MS SQL Server (или иных, кому где удобно)